# Google Maps V3 async gives error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

For a website I'm trying to load the Google Maps script async, because it makes some browser (Firefox) ignore scrolling before all the scripts are loaded from Google.

I looked at the google developers docs and used their script.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async
works all perfect as long as you place it inside a `<script>` tag in your index.html.

But when I place this code for example in my main.js file it isn't working anymore.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/693xK/

Then I found this example on jsfiddle which seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7cu2F/
But over here the same problem. When I place it inside of my main.js file Google Maps isn't showing up. Everything is global. I get the following error but I don't understand what to do about it. I googled the error message but haven't had any luck.

```
TypeError: window.initialize is not a function
```

Comment: are you calling the google maps script before the main.js?

Comment: @paul-ngc Got it, check the fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to add **width and height** to your `#map-canvas`.  Also I checked your fiddle, since you're using `window.onload = loadScript;` so wrap it in head (*left corner, under Frameworks & Extensions*)

```
#map-canvas{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
```

check this [**updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/693xK/1/).

Comment: Hi user1671639,
Thanks for your answer. When I use onload I should include the script in the head? I prefer not to do that.

Here is a link with a real example how the website is constructed. Included with the error. 
[test link](http://tup.li/test/index.html)

Comment: @paul_ngc remove `$(function(){` jquery enclosure in main.js.  this will work.

Comment: yes I tried it by removing it. Then it works :) But how come it doesn't work with the ''$(function(){ ? Trying to learn from this, because I want it to run inside a function and call it whenever I want. But when I do the following:
`var obj = {

 gMaps: function() {
  function initialize() {
    .......
  }

  window.onload = loadScript; 
 }
}

obj.gMaps();`
It gives me the same alert again.